# divergence of the integral

Tags: analysis

I haven't idea how to prove divergence of this integral. 
$\int\limits_0^{\frac{1}{2}} \frac{1}{r^3(\ln(r))^2}\,dr $
Сan you help me?

Comment: The issue is at bound $0$. As $(r \ln r)^2 \to 0$ when $r \to 0$, you have in particular $(r \ln r)^2 < 1$ in a certain vicinity $V$ of $0$, therefore your integrand is larger than $1/r$ in $V$. Can you conclude from here ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dr}{r^3\log^2r}=-\frac{dr^{-2}}{2\log^2r}=-\frac{2dr^{-2}}{\log^2r^{-2}}.$$

Now what about

$$\frac{dt}{\log^2t}$$ integrated to infinity ?